# Webscraping with beautiful soup 4, class not working

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to webscrape, as a personal excersie, the players data from this page:
https://sofifa.com/players
So I want to grab the players ID which is in this kind of line of HTML:

```
<td class = "col col-pi" data-col="pi"> 11111 </td>
```

So what I do is this:
First I get my soup

```
url = 'http://sofifa.com/players'

def soup_making(url):
    my_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(my_page.text, "html.parser")
    return soup


soup = soup_making(url)
```

The I try to do my **scraping** with find_all:

```
test = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'col col-pi'})
print(test)
```

And the output is [], this method has worked for other classes of the same page, but it doesn't work for this particular "col col-pi" as well as some others like "col col-name", but if I scrape this:

```
<td class = "col col-ae" data-col="ae"> 26 </td>
test = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'col col-ae'})
print(test)
```

This works, does anyone knows why is working with some clasess and not with others when I'm using the same method for both? Do you recomend a better way of doing it?

Thanks for the answer @myz540 is so weird that is no picking all the td classes, here is an image of the source code I see:
[Example of the sofifa source code td classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkVmr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I went to the site and inspected the source. I copied your code and grabbed all the `td` elements but I did not find any with `class="col col-pi"`.

```py
soup = soup_making(url)
tags = soup.find_all('td')
all_td_classes = set()
for tag in tags:
    for c in tag.attrs['class']:
        all_td_classes.add(c)

print(all_td_classes)
```

Outputs:

```
{'col-oa', 'col-name', 'col-pt', 'col-vl', 'col', 'col-wg', 'col-comment', 'col-ae', 'col-tt', 'col-avatar'}
False
```

Where are you seeing the player ID?

[image]

Comment: Is so weird that is not picking all the clases:

Comment: Ya, can you screenshot the source where you see that `class`? I couldn't find it at all

Comment: Interesting, I am on chrome and I seem to be seeing far fewer `td` elements than you. I updated my answer with a screenshot. Sorry I wasn't able to help

Comment: thanks for your help, I see what is my issue now, if i just use the sofifa.com url I'll get to scrape the default properties, which are the ones you see, I have to specify in the URL what properties I want in order for my code to scrape the desired classes, so my URL will have to look like this: https://sofifa.com/players?&showCol%5B%5D=pi&showCol%5B%5D=ae&showCol%5B%5D=oa&showCol%5B%5D=pt&showCol%5B%5D=bp&showCol%5B%5D=gu&showCol%5B%5D=le&showCol%5B%5D=vl&showCol%5B%5D=wg&showCol%5B%5D=tt&showCol%5B%5D=pac&showCol%5B%5D=sho&showCol%5B%5D=pas&showCol%5B%5D=dri&showCol%5B%5D=def&showCol%5B%5